# Fetching from firestore and Firebase functions timeout

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a simple function that I am testing locally on the emulator.

```
    exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onRequest(() => {
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("Users")
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, doc.data());
      });
    });
});
```

When I execute the function, it works fine, but shortly after I get this message:

```
     functions: Your function timed out after ~60s. To configure this timeout, see
      https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation.
>  C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:618
>              throw new Error("Function timed out.");
>              ^
>
>  Error: Function timed out.
>      at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\emulator\functionsEmulatorRuntime.js:618:19)
>      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
>      at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7)
```

my expectation was that the function would just end normally since its at the end of the function, is this message saying that I need to do something to indicate the function has finished? Do I need to change something especially when pushing to production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must [terminate a HTTP function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) by sending back a response otherwise it'll run until it times out. Try refactoring your code like this:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // add req, res in functions parameters             ^^^
  return firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("Users")
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, doc.data());
      });
      // Return response
      return res.json({ data: snapshot.docs.map(d => d.data()) })
    });
});
```

Comment: so what I am trying to do is just execute this function at a random time of day from firebase. Of all the triggers, looks like the https.onRequest is the best suited. I don't need the function itself to return anything once completed. I even tried just having a return; at the end and still get the timeout error.

Comment: @Reza you still need to terminate it. Can you add `res.json({})`? Just an empty object to return

Comment: That worked, just doing a return or return "Ok" did not.

Comment: That's a HTTP function so you need to return/end a response unlike background functions where you can return a promise or just return in case of synchronous functions.

Comment: Is this the best function to use if I want to just trigger some action to happen at random times. I haven’t quite figured out how to even trigger this yet. Firebase doesn’t have an option for a random timed function - or is there?

Comment: @Reza scheduled functions are an option but you are saying you want to trigger these randomly.  You can perhaps use [PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/) or [Cloud tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks) and schedule them so they trigger functions on specified time (which can be any unlike Scheduled functions which run on a cron).

Comment: just an FYI, returning result.json({}) works in emulators, but when you upload to functions you get an error 'Upload Error: Unable to parse JSON: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0'. So I had to result.send("Ok") instead.